# What kind of bug is this? I’m not sure if it’s a cockroach

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]Found this bug in my home. Is this a roach?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is almost impossible to say from your photo as the main features are obscured, the subject is badly lit and the body is distorted (crushed?) If you had better photos we might be able to tell. Would also need a location in the world to help ID.

Answer (score 1):

Rove beetle possibly.  Not sure though, and if so it's not clear what kind of rove beetle - it's a large and varied family, and the picture is a bit smudgy.  They seem to usually be harmless/not a pest species, and occasionally wander into houses from outside.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rove_beetle

Doesn't look like any of the types of cockroach I found pictures of on a quick search.  It seems that there are several unrelated species called "cockroaches", but all of them seem to have plain antennae, not "beaded" ones like the insect in your picture, their heads are a different shape, and most of them aren't visibly segmented like that.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockroach

You might have more chance of finding out whether it's a cockroach just by typing "cockroach" into a search engine and looking at some of the image results than by posting here.  I mean, you've got the insect (or had at the time) and we haven't, so you can see it better.

Comment: My impression is also Rove Beetle of some kind.  The big beetle head and mandibles. the smallish partially deployed wings, exposed abdomen and "hunchbacked" look lean in that direction.  However, it's not clear if some of these apparent points are simply artifacts of the squashing it underwent, so that's just an impression.